# Override/Extend Type Declaration Properties

Tags: typescript, types, intellisense, declaration, npm-package

I installed an awesome npm package with its type declaration. But I noticed some mixups & missing pieces in its properties & type declarations.
I need to override or extend those properties to proceed. Please how do I go about it?

Below is a sample implementation of what I need. Thank you.

I got these 2 major errors [ts2717](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2717) & [ts2300](https://typescript.tv/errors/#TS2300)

**NPM Package (node_modules/@types/my-package)**

```
declare module 'my-package' {
    namespace Profile {
        interface Information {
            name: number; // This was an external mistake
        }
        type Hobbies = 'swimming' | 'dancing'
    }
}
```

**My Override (src/@types/index.d.ts)**

```
declare module 'my-package' {
    namespace Profile {
        interface Information {
            name: string; // Needs to be corrected
        }
        type Hobbies = Hobbies | 'running' | 'singing' // Needs to be extended
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
"use strict";
```

**Error**

```
> Duplicate identifier 'Hobbies'.
> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'name' must be of type 'number', but here has type 'string'.
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAED51A7B7ATApgfQLYIK4BtEGdgACALgJ4AOewqJAtGQIYDGA1vQOaIBQSjW9ATolDp42IQHJqdJqw7jQAb06gVMeqjwNGQgAr9YAMwCWORctUWj0Ion4GmQgJLQDsfqnpEjsaGYv-VaHVEAC4YDFQAI1sAblAQUAAVAAsjXFAAd3p0+l9EAA8bfiCsYTSiemYuAJUAX3MA0gpQAAlYWEijPFAAXlBxXAyjVFQrNnkAH374XMYx8QbQevrOBMhQXH5GQibKKyR8gDp4Q6JcbkReASERMX6pLVlEeSULII1cLV19Y1NXmqsRXs2lAzlc7k83l8-xqgWCYVwRH4YziCQAcohEPB0kRYKBoqBGG5BIwbPBFhZ6rDdq12p1un02h0uukpuJ+BhoNB5qA2bgxjz0ZjsaBcfihAUbNAkOTKZxakA)

I tried this *index.d.ts*

```
declare module 'my-package' {
    namespace Profile {
        interface Information {
            name: string;
        }
        type Hobbies = Hobbies | 'running' | 'singing'
    }
}
```

I was expecting vscode intellisense to detect the new type and output the autocomplete and tsc to compile without errors.

Comment: ①​ What are *hoobies*? Sounds inappropriate. Do you mean *hobbies*? ② You simply can't merge in conflicting declarations or re-define type aliases like that (e.g., [ms/TS#25495](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25495) and [ms/TS#36146](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36146) are not implemented); you'll have to fork the offending declaration file locally and modify them, as annoying as that is.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is actually *hobbies*. Thanks for noting that. @jcalz

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thank you @jcalz

So I applied 2 solutions.

1. I had to clone the entire *.d.ts file of the package locally. And then uninstall type declaration (`npm uninstall @types/the-package`)
   So that tsconfig would only detect my own corrected declarations.
2. I just created and extend the corrected `interface` & `type` while `Omit<...>` the faulty properties and fields, And the applied the new interfaces `as FixInformation`

```
import { Information, Hobbies } from 'the-package'

interface FixedInformation extends Omit<Information, 'name'> {
  name: string;
}

type FixedHobbies = Hobbies | 'codinig' | 'debugging';

const profile = new Profile();

profile.setInformation({
 name: 'Vixson',
 hobbies: 'anything' as any // Use any to bypass when assigninig
});

profile.getInformation((info: FixedInformation) =>{
 const first_name = info.name.split(' ')[0]; // Now I can run string function here instead of number ✅

 switch(info.hobbies as FixedHobbies){
  case 'coding': // <- intellisence auto picks the new types
  console.log('Hello Earth');
  break;
 }
})
```